# iCarousel repeating Images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode5, icarousel

I am using amazing iCarousel library in my app. But i am facing a problem. I am using this code to populate data into carousel.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
   //return the total number of items in the carousel
   return [items count];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;
UIImageView *imageView = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
if (view == nil)
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 60, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -150)];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width - 60, width - 60);
    imageView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [view addSubview:imageView];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 240.0, width -60, 260.0)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:22];
    label.numberOfLines = 5;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.tag = 1;
    [view addSubview:label];
}
else
{
    //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
    label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
}

NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[[items objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"Image File Name: %@", imageName);
NSLog(@"Image Explanation: %@", [[items objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1]);
[imageView setImage:[ UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:imageName atSize:CGSizeMake( 150, 130 ) ]];
label.text = [[items objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1];

return view;
}
```

numberOfItemsInCarousel returns 38 but carousel only shows 6 images and then repeating them in cycle. Lable text is showing according to array index correctly.
How can i Fix it?

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue did you got the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting `imageView` from reused views, read the line

```
[imageView setImage:[ UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:imageName atSize:CGSizeMake( 150, 130 ) ]];
```

as

```
[nil setImage:[ UIImage imageWithPDFNamed:imageName atSize:CGSizeMake( 150, 130 ) ]];
```

when `view != nil`. Get the `imageView` in the same way you do it for `label`.